# how to create a new object that one of its fields is the reference of another object?

Tags: java, android, class, oop

I like to create a new object that one of its fields is the reference of another object.

UIViewObject is the class definition the object and oView is the field I want to reference to another object:

```
 public class UIViewObject {    
    public View oView;
    public Integer oEnabled;
    public Integer oVisible;

    public UIViewObject() {
        oEnabled = UIAction.UISettingView.ENABLED;
        oVisible = UIAction.UISettingView.VISIBLE;  
    }
    public UIViewObject setObject(View OView) {
        oView = OView;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setObject(GL_TextView OView) {
        oView = OView;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setEnabled() {
        oEnabled = UIAction.UISettingView.ENABLED;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setDisabled() {
        oEnabled = UIAction.UISettingView.DISABLED;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setShow() {
        oVisible = UIAction.UISettingView.VISIBLE;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setHide() {
        oVisible = UIAction.UISettingView.GONE;
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setObjectEnabled() {
        oView.setEnabled(true);
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setObjectDisabled() {
        oView.setEnabled(false);
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setObjectShow() {
        oView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return this;
    }
    public UIViewObject setObjectHide() {
        oView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return this;
    } 
}
```

This is how I create the object:

```
 HashMap<String, UIViewObject> viewsAction = new HashMap<String,UIViewObject>();
 public void setTextView_Finalized_Show() {
   UIViewObject newO = new UIViewObject();
   viewsAction.put("txvFinalized",   newO.setObject(mUIInvoice.txvFinalized).setShow());
 }
 public void setTextView_Finalized_Hide() {
UIViewObject newO = new UIViewObject();
viewsAction.put("txvFinalized", newO.setObject(mUIInvoice.txvFinalized).setHide());
 }
```

txvFinalized is a public variable that is null by the time newO is creating but after that it gets value. I want when txvFinalized gets value in oNew the value of oView changes.

How can I define the field to be the reference to for example txvFinalized?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I am not sure what your asking. It seems as though your just asking how to set `oView` to being a reference to the same object as `txvFinalized`, but you've already shown you can do that in the question.

Comment: Hi Rudi, the problem is it doesn't work. I create newO  object in initializing of some classes but when the UI comes up actually txtFinalized gets the value but oViwe in newO is still null. !!!  :(

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: The concept is business logic classes control the UI element (disable, enable, show, hide,...). when all classes define, initialize methods are calling. initialize method of business logics calles before UI initialize method. So in Business logic initialize method, the variable oView is defined but still null. after that UI initialize methods calls and set the value to public variable txtFinalize. when I want to show a page I go throw the UI setting by business logic to show, hide, disable,... the elements. but because the oView in newO is still null. is doesn't work.

Comment: Just let U know I create UIViewObject for each elemet (view) in the xml file in business logic and save all setting in a hashmap. then UI read the hashmap and set theirs appearance. is I first call initialize of UI classes then call initialize if business classes it works, because forexample txvFinalise has the value before business class starts. but the business logic of the application is like calls all initialiaze method of business classes before UI. :(

Comment: I just ran an example of your logic through a test and it's working correctly. The problem must be outside of the class you've posted up. Do you have more of the code relating to this you could post up, and maybe the stack trace?

Comment: I edited the part I new the object to the what I created here. I just wanted the code simple so eliminated some parts. setTextView_Finalized_Show() and setTextView_Finalized_Hide() ,,... calls from business logic when the txtFinalize object is still null.

Comment: in your try did you create the oView with null first and then set a value to oView?

Comment: Yep, I did. Are you positive `mUIInvoice.txvFinalized` isn't null when you pass it into the `setObject()` method?